# Why is String not an Enum in Elixir?

Tags: enums, elixir

I come from a Python background and I am currently learning Elixir. I can understand some of the concepts from Elixir with my knowledge from Python.<sup>[1]</sup>

In my mental model I understand Elixir's `Enum` to be what is called an `Iterable` in Python: It can be sliced, indexed, sorted, zipped, it can be enumerated (!), and so on. However, I spotted one big difference: In Python, strings comply with the `Iterable` protocol, but Elixir's `String`s are not `Enum`s. I guess, there must be a deeper conceptual or computational reason behind this. Just looking at the specs of `Enum` all the functions of `Enum` would make sense (from a business logic point of view) to be applied to `String`. But in order to apply them, I always have to transfer a String to an Enum of its graphemes.

So, my question is:

**Why is the `String` data type not implemented as an `Enum` in the specific context of Elixir?**

---

<sub>[1] For instance, both Elixir `Stream` and `Process` seem to share ideas with Python's `Generator` — a `Stream` is basically a `Generator` which does not allow sending values into it, and a `Process` is a full-blown `Generator`.</sub>

Comment: This is one of those "you need to ask the creators" questions; folks here could guess at it, but the reason is always going to be either "because the implementers decided that" or maybe buried in a development mailing list somewhere.

Comment: @TylerH I disagree. And I think this question being closed is based on a misunderstanding. I am not asking for a psychological reason in the sense of: "What did the developers think when they did this", but rather for the conceptual or computational arguments against this implementation. This is just a matter of facts, and it is independent of what the developers had had for breakfast the day they made this decision.

Comment: The problem is the "computational arguments" are chosen by the authors. They could have chosen other arguments they preferred. So it still boils down to someone's opinion.

Comment: @TylerH I reworded my question to clarify what I mean.

Comment: One cannot “make `String` an `Enum`” in [tag:elixir] because there are no objects. Both `String` and `Enum` are _modules_, just a bunch of exported functions. `String` exports functions working with strings, `Enum` exports functions working with enumerables. That’s it.

Comment: Strings in Elixir are UTF-8 encoded binaries. If you want to enumerate a binary, which is just a blob of data, you need to specify *how*. For strings, there are [`String.graphemes/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#graphemes/1), [`String.codepoints/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#codepoints/1), and [`String.to_charlist/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#to_charlist/1) functions that will give you a list that you can enumerate.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Thanks for your comment! I would consider your comment an answer, would upvote and accept it. Unfortunately, I cannot, because the question is closed :)

Comment: Such is life  I also think your question is opinion-based. Maybe it could be re-opened if you changed it to "how do you enumerate a string in Elixir?". Anyway, glad to help.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Your edit didn't make it objective (what is "most important" and who decided that? And how many arguments should we put forth?). Adam's suggestion is on-topic/objective, however.

Comment: This is not an opinion based question, there are technical reasons why strings are not implemented as Enums in Elixir and it has numerous practical implications in daily-life programming. This is a totally legit question, specially for someone starting with Elixir. I'm voting to reopen this one.